# Best way to multithread UI?

Tags: c++, qt

As stated clearly in the documentation, Qt GUI must be accessed from main thread only.  For complex app with multiple large and busy tables, this can be a bottleneck just from all the font-size text metrics calculations Qt likes to do.  The only alternative I can think of is multi-tasking with separate processes.  The tables are currently about as fast as you can get, custom model that is direct-mapped to a cache that is fed from another thread using dataChanged() calls on the most conservative set of changed cells.  I've already profiled with vTune, 70% of the app time is now in Qt rendering code.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Last time I dealt with Qt (Qt 4.6 or so), I was feeding a large model (a few hundred thousand lines of spreadsheet data) to a QTableView. I also noticed that the font metrics calculation showed up in my profiler output. Turned out that [`QHeaderView::sectionSizeFromContents`](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/itemviews/qheaderview.cpp#line2556) was the culprit, it calculated the row height based on the font for every new row, even if all rows have the same height. We replaced it with a simple custom header view returning a fixed height - helped a lot!

Comment: Did you try `setUniformRowHeights()`? I don't know if it would have fixed the problem in your case (it once did for me), I'm just curious.

Comment: How complex are these tables? [QTableView has a batch size property](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qlistview.html#batchSize-prop) that can be set to restrict the updates of your view to a limited section of the model. Perhaps your tables can implement something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I havn't used QT, but accessing GUI from only one thread (the GUI thread) is a known matter in almost any GUI I'm familiar with. I used 2 solutions for this case, of which I prefer the first one:

1) Your form will update the GUI (table, in this case) at timer intervals. The timer is activated on the GUI thread's events. At those timer events you read the data from global vars and update your table. The global vars can be updated by as many threads as you wish. You might need to synch (semaphores, for examples) the access to the global vars.

2) In many GUI APIs threads can update the GUI by handing the GUI thread a function (or an object) and ask it to execute it ASAP on its context. The calling thread meanwhile blocks, until the GUI fulfilled the action. I can recall three such functions - `Invoke`, `InvokeLater` from Java and C#, or `wx.CallAfter` of wxPython.

Comment: +1: I've used technique #1 with GTK+ on Linux, and it works really well. You definitely want to spin off non-GUI tasks into separate threads if possible, or do them in an "idle handler" in the GUI thread.

Answer (score 3):

Use a variant of MVC pattern and make the model multithread

Answer (score 2):

If your table entries and methods are done in several steps, you can call  **QCoreApplication::processEvents()** to update the qt ui in between the calculations. Another thing you can do is run everything on different thread and emit signals from the thread when the calculations are complete. At the end, the updates are done on the ui from the main thread but asynchronously. To connect to a signal from a different thread you'll have to use **qRegisterMetaType<>**.